# Could not find developer disk image stack overflow xcode 7.2, iOS 9.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, diskimage, ios9.3.1

After updating my devcie to iOS 9.3.1 Xocde giving  "could not find developer disk image". 
I am using xcode 7.2. Please help.

[image: Screenshot for error message]

Answer (score 6):

You need to download Xcode v.7.3. to use > 9.3 iOS version. And to upgrade to Xcode v.7.3. your Mac OSX should be upgrade to 10.11.5 or greater at least.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/